# Fluent Nhibernate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, fluent-nhibernate

I am trying to use Fluent NHibernate with ASP.NET MVC 3 and I cannot seem to find a tutorial that explains how to get it all configured with ASP.NET MVC. I mainly am wondering where to put the ISession building function and how to call it when I need it. I see so many different implementations but none of them specify where they put this code. So if anyone can explain how to get it all configured to work with MVC 3 or where a very detailed tutorial is, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you doing any dependency injection?

Comment: Well I want to use StructureMap but I am just starting to set everything up and was starting with Fluent NHibernate first. But if I need to set up StructureMap up first to make it easier, I can do that. Im VERY new to trying to do Enterprise like coding and am pretty confused. LOL

Comment: i'm not sure that there is any real tutorial on how to get started, but that's a stack i'm familiar with.  i'm actually looking at the code right now that you'd probably need to get started, but its quite a bit of code, so i'm debating where i should put it

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at S#arp Architecture.
It's a pretty solid architectural framework to work with ASP.NET MVC & NHibernate. They have a decent documentation and there's some sample projects to look at.

http://www.sharparchitecture.net/

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using dependency injection you can try something like this

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{

    public static ISession CurrentSession
    {
        get { return (ISession)HttpContext.Current.Items["current.session"]; }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Items["current.session"] = value; }
    }

    private static ISessionFactory _session_factory;
    private static object _session_factory_lock = new object();

    protected static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
    {

        if (_session_factory != null) return _session_factory;

        if (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConnection"] != null)
        {
            var conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConnection"];
            SqlServerSessionFactoryBuilder fb = new SqlServerSessionFactoryBuilder(conn.ConnectionString);
            _session_factory = fb.GetSessionFactory();
            return _session_factory;
        }

        throw new Exception("Cannot build session factory, connection string is not defined.");

    }


    public MvcApplication()
    {
        _session_factory = CreateSessionFactory();

        BeginRequest += delegate
        {

            try
            {
                CurrentSession = _session_factory.OpenSession();
            }
            catch (FluentConfigurationException ex)
            {
                logger.FatalException(string.Format("Error configuring the database {0}", ex.Message), ex);

            }

        };


        EndRequest += delegate
        {
            if (CurrentSession != null)
            {
                if (CurrentSession.Transaction != null && CurrentSession.Transaction.IsActive)
                {
                    logger.Error("Rolling back uncommited transaction");
                    CurrentSession.Transaction.Rollback();
                }
                else
                {
                    CurrentSession.Flush();           
                }
                CurrentSession.Close();
            }
        };

        Error += delegate
        {
            var error = this.Server.GetLastError();
            logger.ErrorException(string.Format("Unhandled error : {0}", error.Message), error);  
        };
    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);


    }

}
```